# How can I determine why exactly UAC is blocking an app from running/installing?

Tags: windows-7, security, microsoft-outlook, uac

Windows 7 Professional (Fully updated).

UAC seems to be preventing an Outlook Add-in from installing/running correctly.  When I disable UAC and restart, it works fine.  When I re-enable UAC and restart, the add-in stops working.

Is there a log that can provide more information?  In the event viewer I see the following (process names have been renamed to protect the innocent :D)

```
<DATABASE> <EXE NAME="foo.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="foo.dll" SIZE="961024" CHECKSUM="0xFCCA9721" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="04/29/2010 18:16:53" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/29/2010 18:16:53" EXPORT_NAME="foo.dll" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="fooagent.exe" SIZE="284560" CHECKSUM="0x60BEE68C" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.0.0.753" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.2.0.753" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.2.0.753" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Foo Module" PRODUCT_NAME="Foo Product" FILE_VERSION="5.2.0.753" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="foo.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="foo" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2002-2011 Foo, Inc.  All rights reserved." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x48D1C" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.0.0.753" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.2.0.753" LINK_DATE="08/05/2011 23:56:34" UPTO_LINK_DATE="08/05/2011 23:56:34" VER_LANGUAGE="English (United States) [0x409]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
```

What is GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY?  Is that a specific rule in UAC? If so, what is it looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can download Microsoft's Application Compatability Kit. Then use either the Standard User Analyzer or Standard User Analyzer Wizard and it gives a very **detailed** report of any violations.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check it out.  What I'm noticing is that some workstations will have problems and others won't.  Not sure why.